# SEO Strategies: Directory, separate domain, or sub-domain?

Tags: url, blogs, seo

What is the optimal SEO strategy for storing a blog?

1) In a directory: `www.example.com/blog`

2) In a separate domain: `www.exampleblog.com`

3) In a sub-domain: `www.blog.example.com`

With a directory, the repetitions earned by the blog are directly transferred to the main domain (`www.example.com`). With a separate domain, any links to my site would count as backlinks.

I'm leaning towards option 1. What other pros and cons should I consider?

Comment: I just re-read your question. Do you mean `www.example.com/blog` versus `blog.example.com`? Or is your question about having your blog in a directory versus using an entirely different domain name, and using that for your blog?

Comment: yes my question was about having the blog in a directory versus an entirely different domain for the blog. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is comprehensive, **[Sub-domain versus sub-directory](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34173/subdomains-vs-subdirectory-status-as-of-2012)** (via Webmasters SE). It was updated in November 2012. Look at **[this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/30944/8359)** too, as it specifically describes, with a huge chart, what effect sub-folders (meaning sub-directory in this context) versus sub-domains have on SEO, and how use of reverse proxy can affect blog SEO. The gist of it is that a sub-domain is preferable to a sub-directory.

**EDIT**
I may have mis-read the question. If the choice is between
`mywebsitename.com/blog`
versus
`mywebsitenameblog.com`

then I would definitely recommend using the sub-directory. This is why:

- If you use an entirely different domain name, even if it is your website's domain with the four letters `blog` concatenated, it will be confusing to users, as no one does that!
- You will need to pay for a second domain and that costs more money.
- You'll be doing something that is inconsistent with typical website naming conventions, which I'd avoid if I were concerned about SEO and were developing an e-commerce website. I don't know if it will negatively affect SEO ranking, but it won't help, as it will be an entirely different domain name, without any of the positive reputation or credibility of your primary domain name.
- It will be four characters longer, which is never good, as it will be less convenient, more difficult to remember, etc.

Better yet, use a sub-domain of your primary website for your blog. To summarize, you should do the following, in order of best to worst:

`blog.mywebsitename.com`
`mywebsitename.com/blog`
`mywebsitenameblog.com`

Comment: Thanks a lot the inforgraphic and your explanation were both very helpful. I've decided to go with
    www.example.com/blog/ 

btw I'd like to know how 
blog.example.com is better than example.com/blog/ up till now I was under the impression they both were treated equally from SEO point of view..

Answer (score 0):

There is slight difference depending on which search engine is going to look at and add or subtract value to your blog on basis of this decision.

Read this blog post [from Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/). or [Watch this video for summary](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=_MswMYk05tk)

If you go for another domain then search engine expect it to be separate content and not much relation in terms of your main domain rank.

I would install the blog in sub-directory called blog and stop worrying about actual juice from search engines as it may vary from one to another.